# How to open the folder recursively using NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace?

Tags: ios, macos

I am developing an application in which, when a usb pen drive is mounted, this application directly opens the usb drive and shows all folder views.

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] selectFile:@"/volumes/LIVE/" inFileViewerRootedAtPath:@"/Volumes/LIVE/"];
```

Here "LIVE" is pen drive name. When opening the folder only till LIVE path its opened but i could not view the folders inside "Live" how to access the child folders available in "LIVE".

Thanks n advance!

Comment: I don't understand the question; do you mean open the USB stick within *Finder*?

Comment: yes, i derived all details of the usb and everything working fine but could not open the recursive folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got it

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSArray *theFiles =  [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/volumes/LIVE/"]includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLNameKey]
                                                        options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles error:nil];

[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] activateFileViewerSelectingURLs:theFiles];
```